# Laravel carbon and subDays

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to get list of users with `created_at` date more than `30 days` but it get users with even today date.

## Logic

1. Get users which registration dates +30 days.
2. If their verification date is null delete them.

## Issue

even if I register today and my verification date is null my account will delete.

## Code

```
$date = Carbon::today()->subDays(30);

$deleteUsers = User::where('email_verified_at', null)->where('created_at', '>', $date)->delete();
```

Comment: The logic should be less than date, not greater than.

Comment: @Devon let me try :D

Comment: @Devon working now thanks.

Comment: @Devon you should post this as answer so that it will help other also.

Answer (score 7):

```
$date=Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
$deleteUsers = User::where('email_verified_at', null)->where('created_at', '<', $date)->delete();
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: It's running. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

We compare this date code with the previous one if it was smaller
code:

```
            $date=Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('Y-m-d');
            $t=Trash_form::where('updated_at','<=',$date)->value('id');
            return Trash_form::where('id',$t)->delete();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Additionally, where does `App\Trash_form` come from? Is that a built-in feature, or did you randomly add new classes?